# Why the two expressions of total variation distance are equivalent?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

In a stochastic processes textbook, I find the definition of total variation distance is $\|\pi - \nu\|_{TV} = \max\{|\pi(A) - \nu(A)|:A\subset S\}$ where $\pi$ and $\nu$ are two probability measures on $S$.

It then says it is easy to see that the maximum is obtained on the set $A = \{x:\pi(x) \ge \nu(x)\}$. Therefore $\|\pi -\nu\|_{TV} = \sum\limits_{\pi(x)\ge\nu(x)}(\pi(x) - \nu(x))$.

Why this statement is right? I thought according to the definition $\|\pi - \nu\|_{TV} = \|\pi - \nu\|_\infty$.

Comment: When positive difference and negative difference appear together, they compensate each other. So the maximum is achieved with either as many as possible positive differences or as many as possible negative differences.  Since we are dealing with probability measures, the absolute values of all the positive differences and of all the negative differences are the same

Comment: @PetiteEtincelle I guess the problem is that I know nothing of measure theory. I think I should read a measure theory book.

Comment: Because $\max|\pi(A)-\nu(A)|=\max(\pi(A)-\nu(A))$ and because $A=\{\pi\ge\nu\}$ (or $A=\{\pi>\nu\}$, by the way) obviously achieve this maximum.

Comment: @Did Yeah I have recognized that, I was confused by what $A$ stands for when I asked this question. Could you please write this as an answer so that I can set the question solved?

Answer (score 2):

I follow closely [S. Roch, Chapter 1:](https://www.math.wisc.edu/%7Eroch/mdp/) Define $B:= \{x : \mu(x) \geq \nu(x)\}$. Then, for any $A \subseteq V$ we have that

> \begin{equation*}
>     \mu(A)-\nu(A) \leq \mu(A\cap B) - \nu(A \cap B) \leq \mu(B) - \nu(B),
> \end{equation*}

were the first inequality comes from the monotonicity of the measures and the definition of $B$, and the same for the second inequality. Also, we have that, similarly,
\begin{align*}
    \nu(A) - \mu(A) \leq \nu(A \cap B^c) - \mu(A\cap B^c) \leq \nu(B^c) - \mu(B^c) \\= 1-\nu(B)-1+\mu(B) = \mu(B)-\nu(B).
\end{align*}
This means that
\begin{equation*}
   \vert\mu(A) - \nu(A)\vert \leq  \mu(B)-\nu(B) 
\end{equation*}
The equality is achieved when $A=B$. Hence we know that the supremum is given by this relation, we can simply re-write in the form of

> \begin{equation}
>     \mu(B) - \nu(B) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\mu(B)-\nu(B) + \nu(B^c) - \mu(B^c)\right) 
> \end{equation}

But $$\frac{1}{2}(\mu(B)-\nu(B)) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{x\in B}(\mu(x)-\nu(x))$$ and $$\frac{1}{2}(\nu(B^c)-\mu(B^c)) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{x\in B^c}\vert \mu(x) - \nu(x)\vert$$ So finally we have that
\begin{equation*}
    \mu(B) - \nu(B) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{x\in B}\vert \mu(x)-\nu(x)\vert + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{x\in B^c}\vert \mu(x) - \nu(x)\vert = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{x\in V}\vert \mu(x)-\nu(x) \vert.
\end{equation*}

Comment: A silly question... where is "$\max\{|\pi(A) - \nu(A)|:A\subset S\}$" in your proof?